# Какая версия метода лучше, статическая или обычная?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Какая версия метода лучше?

```
public  Anchor FindEmptyAnchor0()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < anchors.Length; i++)
    {
        if (anchors[i].transform == null)
            continue;
        if (anchors[i].attachedTile == null)
            return anchors[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

или же эта?

```
public static Anchor FindEmptyAnchorStatic(VoxelTile tile)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tile.anchors.Length; i++)
    {
        if (tile.anchors[i].transform == null)
            continue;
        if (tile.anchors[i].attachedTile == null)
            return tile.anchors[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

В плане функционала, как я понял особой разницы нету, вопрос наверное только в красоте, вот так примерно я хотел использовать эти методы

```
public VoxelTile AddTile(VoxelTile basic)
{
    basic.FindEmptyAnchor().SomeMethod();
    VoxelTile secondary;
    VoxelTile.FindEmptyAnchorStatic(secondary).SomeMethod();
    // дальше что там сделать
}
```

Comment: В чём смысл статики в данном случае?

Comment: Не использовать внутренний anchors а только anchors.anchors

Comment: Думаю Автор имел ввиду что ему нужно вернуть FindEmptyAnchor у любого массива. По хорошему это решается и без функции

Comment: secondary у вас null в данный момент

Comment: tile.anchors.Length и это выкинет ошибку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данная возможность - спецификация языка. Использовать вам, либо нет, зависит от задач, решаемых вами. Но, так уж случилось, что статичные методы и поля требуют другого подхода к использованию.

```
public Anchor FindEmptyAnchor0()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < anchors.Length; i++)
    {
        if (anchors[i].transform != null && anchors[i].attachedTile == null)
            return anchors[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

А по-хорошему вам не нужен никакой метод

```
Anchors[] anchors = ...;

Anchor first = anchors.FirstOrDefault(anchor => anchors.transform != null && anchors.attachedTile == null);
```

> **FirstOrDefault** - The default value for reference and nullable types is null.

Comment: public VoxelTile AddTile(VoxelTile basic)
    {
        basic.FindEmptyAnchor();
    }

Comment: наверное всё же public VoxelTile AddTile(VoxelTile basic) { return basic.FindEmptyAnchor(); }

Comment: извиняюсь за первый комментарий, вот что я хотел написать.
В плане функционала, как я понял особой разницы нету, вопрос наверное только в красоте, вот так примерно я хотел использовать эти методы

`public VoxelTile AddTile(VoxelTile basic)
    {
        basic.FindEmptyAnchor().SomeMethod();
        VoxelTile secondary;
        VoxelTile.FindEmptyAnchorStatic(secondary).SomeMethod();
        // дальше что там сделать
    }`

Comment: FindEmptyAnchor().SomeMethod(); могут быть проблемы. Нужно на null проверять. Не упускайте такого никогда